# When to increase the log cleaner threads?

Tags: apache-kafka

In which cases is it recommended to increase the number of log cleaner threads?

Are there recommendation about that?

For example if I have many partitions, then do I have to increase the number of log cleaner threads ( 1000 partition -> 1 thread, 5000 -> 5 threads, etc )?

Thanks

Comment: I think partition/segment size matters more than just some set partition number, but you shouldn't increase the threads much more than the cores available on the broker

Comment: Ok, so there are recommendation for that? For example: 100MB partition size -> 1 log cleaner thread, 200MB partition size -> 2 log cleaner threads, etc

Comment: I think the last Kafka cluster I worked on had only 8 logcleaner threads, and stored several TB of data. Of course, if there is less data, then 8 threads are still available

Comment: @OneCricketeer Why did you choose exactly 8 log cleaner threads? So I would like to know when do I have to increase the logcleaner threads.

Comment: Probably because the servers were octa-core. Like I said, you shouldn't really go beyond that. You can max it out, and leave it there. Nothing really wrong with having idle threads